# Is there standard Python class to do boolean operations on float ranges?

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I need to collect multiple pieces of information about approximate value of a float variable. The information looks like "39 < x < 41" or just "x < 14.4". Also, the variable has its ultimate min and max values.

I would want to have a class that contains such information in form of float intervals. I would also like to perform Boolean operations on such intervals so that it would look like:

```
float_interval(1,5) and float_interval(2,6) == float_interval(2,5)
float_interval(1,2) and float_interval(3,4) == None
float_interval(1,2) or float_interval(3,4) == i_do_not_know_yet
```

Am I describing some well-known class or I am to write it myself?

If anyone interested the variable is a fetus gestational age in weeks during pregnancy. In many case-control studies fetal age is not always mentioned directly, but instead there is an information on pregnancy trimester or whehter delivery was term or preterm and so on. Hence, I can infer approximate gestational age and put it to the corresponding category.

Comment: There is a package named [intervaltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree/2.1.0) which allows you to perform some operations on intervals efficiently. It hasn't been updated for quite a while, but it could either work for you or give you a hint what to look for.

Comment: @zvone haha, you have a point :)

Comment: There is no such class in the standard library.  The class would have to represent a finite union of intervals, as your last example shows.  It's relatively straight-forward to implement, but will be subject to the inherent accuracy limitations of floating point numbers.

Comment: What do you gain from doing this that you can't solve with the basic math functions?

Comment: @TemporalWolf I can use basic math functions, but I also will need store results somwhere. Besides, I want this thing to be reusable in order not to rewrite similar if then statements for each new combination of conditions.

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко Let me rephrase: The example comparisons you used are cryptic: if I came across those in a program I wouldn't have any idea what you were trying to do. It makes a lot more sense to me to write a `interval_union(inter1, inter2)` function instead of a module for allowing boolean comparisons. I feel like this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378): What is the end goal?

Comment: @TemporalWolf It's not possible to overload `and` and `or` in Python anyway.  The best you can do is overload the bitwise operators `&` and `|` instead.  However, I don't think it matters much for the question.  Overloaded operators are just a special kind of function.  In the answer I gave I chose to use function names like `union` and `intersection`, since I represented finite unions of intervals as simple list instead of members of a custom class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very capable sympy package has an `Interval` class builtin. Example code:

```
import sympy
I1 = sympy.Interval(1, 5)
I2 = sympy.Interval(2, 6)
I3 = I1 & I2
print(I3)
```

See the [sympy interval documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/sets.html#interval) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple proof-of-concept implementation of logic to apply boolean functions to finite unions of intervals.  The finite unions of intervals are represented as list of (start, end) pairs.

```
import functools
import heapq
import itertools

def iter_intervals(tag, interval_set):
    for start, end in interval_set:
        yield start, tag, True
        yield end, tag, False

def apply_boolean_function(f, *interval_sets):
    states = [False] * len(interval_sets)
    result_state = False
    result = []
    for boundary, index, new_state in heapq.merge(*itertools.starmap(
            iter_intervals, enumerate(interval_sets))):
        states[index] = new_state
        new_result_state = f(states)
        if new_result_state != result_state:
            result_state = new_result_state
            if new_result_state and result and result[-1] == boundary:
                result.pop()
            else:
                result.append(boundary)
    return zip(*[iter(result)] * 2)

union = functools.partial(apply_boolean_function, any)
intersection = functools.partial(apply_boolean_function, all)
complement = functools.partial(apply_boolean_function,
                               lambda states: not states[0] and states[1])
```

Examples (Python 2):

```
>>> union([(2, 4), (6, 8)], [(5, 7)])
[(2, 4), (5, 8)]
>>> intersection([(1, 5)], [(2, 6)])
[(2, 5)]
```

In Python 3, the return value will be a lazy `zip()` object instead of a list.  You can add a call to `list()` to the return statement in `apply_boolean_function()` to get a list instead.